# Equivalent of grep -l for filenames in zipfile

Tags: bash, grep, compression

Given a set of zip files, is there an easy way to list only those zipfiles that contain files whose names match a given pattern, cf. using `grep -l` to list only files whose contents contain lines matching a given pattern?

The best I've been able to come up with is

```bash
for i in $ZIPFILE_LIST
> do j=$(basename $i)
> unzip -l $i > /tmp/$j
> grep -l $PATTERN /tmp/$j
> rm /tmp/$j
> done
```

but it's fairly hacky and without e.g. passing the `grep` output through `sed` (with various escaping headaches) it's going to tell you which files you care about, but it's not actually going to give you the full paths in a form you can then pass on to something else. It seems like this is a reasonably common use case and there ought to be some better out-of-the-box tool or combination of tools to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
unzip -l files.zip | grep filename
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `zipgrep`, which is installed in stock Ubuntu (so maybe installed on your system). It's a shell script that uses unzip and egrep internally.

Comment: See comments on [Iain's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/599810/39209) -- I'm not looking for matching files, I'm looking for matching filenames.

Comment: Have you tried `zipgrep -l`? It works for me. Sorry if I didn't spell it out.

Comment: I realise that this doesn't match your description ("contain files whose names match a given pattern"), but I think it matches your code, and your `grep -l` example.

Comment: It doesn't, because I'm not unzipping the zipfiles, I'm just listing their contents (`unzip -l`).

Answer (score 0):

Would the [Python zipfile module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) help solve your problem?

eg:

```
import zipfile

def findfileinzip(source_filename, pattern):
    print(pattern)
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename,'r')
    for member in zf.namelist():
        if member.find(pattern) != -1:
            print(member)
```